# Add a menu item to the logged in users author page?

Tags: menus, author

I am trying to add a menu item titled something like "my posts" or "my profile" that would take the logged in user to their author page

Comment: you can use [`is_user_logged_in`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) and  [`get_author_posts_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_author_posts_url/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`wp_nav_menu_items`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_items/) filter for this, and check if user logged in, and use [`get_author_posts_url($autho_id)`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_author_posts_url/) as bravokeyl suggested:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', function( $items, $args ) {
    $index = 'top-menu'; // menu index key, if you're not sure then var_dump( $args->theme_location )
    global $current_user;
    if ( $current_user->ID && $index === $args->theme_location ) {
        $items .= sprintf(
            '<li id="menu-item-my-posts" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-my-posts menu-item-my-posts"><a href="%s">%s</a></li>',
            get_author_posts_url( $current_user->ID ),
            'My Posts'
        );
    }
    return $items;
}, 10, 2);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Samuel. I tried entering the above code into the functions.php (really its a site specific plugin but it should link to functions.php). It didnt seem to work though. Am I adding it to the wrong place? Or do I have to do something before entering the above code?